# OpenWRT - route all the traffic through Tor

Tags: anonymity

Passing through all the traffic in the router to Tor sounds like a good idea.

But there aren't any good documentations about the implementation of this idea.

Could anyone please explain, how can someone, that has an OpenWRT flashed, example cheap router (with Gbit links and N wifi and USB): TL-WR1043ND configure it to route all the traffic that goes through it via Tor?

So if a user connects via cable or wifi to the router, all the traffic would be automagically routed to Tor network, without any client-side configuration.

The setup could be used in internet cafe's or wherever "free" internet is need to be deployed, and we don't want to face the legal consequences of what our wireless clients did on the internet..

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/OpenWRT) for this setup on the Tor project website is excellent:
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/OpenWRT

Since you have OpenWRT installed already you can skip ahead a few steps in the instructions.

The only thing that is outdated in the Tor project website documentation link there is that you no longer need to do:

```
opkg install iptables-mod-nat iptables-mod-nat-extra
```

because those iptables packages have been inluded in the generic iptables package since openWRT 11.

You might also want to check for hardware compatibility on the OpenWRT website:
http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd

Make sure you have at least 8mb flash memory or you will need to seek out other hardware.